# Can I force LWP::UserAgent to accept an expired SSL certificate?

Tags: perl, https, lwp

I would like to know whether it is possible to force LWP::UserAgent to accept an expired SSL certificate for a single, well-known server. The issue is slightly complicated by the Squid proxy in between.

I went as far as to set up a debugging environment like:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Debug qw(+);
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $proxy = 'http://proxy.example.net:8118';
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new( file => 'cookies.tmp' );
my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$agent->proxy( [ 'http' ], $proxy );
$agent->cookie_jar( $cookie_jar );

$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = $proxy;
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;
$ENV{HTTPS_VERSION} = 3;
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_DIR}    = '/etc/ssl/certs';
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_FILE}    = '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt';

$agent->get( 'https://www.example.com/');

exit;
```

Fortunately the issue was eventually fixed on the remote server before I was able to come up with my own solution, but I would like to be able to optionally circumvent the problem should it arise again (the underlying service had been disrupted for several hours before I was called into action).

I would favor a solution at the LWP::UserAgent level over one based on the underlying Crypt::SSLeay or openSSL implementations, if such a solution exists, since I prefer not to relax security for other unrelated applications. Of course I am still looking for such a solution myself, in my copious free time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Updated to address comment**

To bypass *all* certificate checks you can set the [agent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) up to not verify the certificate.

```
$agent->ssl_opts(verify_hostname => 0);
```

The agent will also pass settings down to the SSL socket implementation being used. For example, with[`IO::Socket::SSL`](http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.962/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm) you can set `SSL_verify_mode` to `0x00`.

```
$agent->ssl_opts(SSL_verify_mode => 0x00);
```

Comment: This is sometimes quoted as a solution, but it did not seem to work in my case; I did not have the time to test it extensively, though, and I might well have been in error.

I plan to verify whether this works or not for me in a test environment.

Comment: Have just had to deal with some perl legacy code, the verify_hostname setting works for me, setting it immediately after construction, before headers etc. I did not need to set SSL_verify_mode.

Answer (score 12):

Try overriding the SSL certificate validation with

```
$agent->ssl_opts(verify_hostname => 0,
              SSL_verify_mode => 0x00);
```

before you do the https request.